# Call Dialog Task in C#?

Tags: c#, botframework

Let's say i'm calling a child Dialog from another one
context.Call(new childDialog(), ResumeDialog);

and let's say childDialog is something like this:

```
public class StartDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        blabla
    }

    public async Task ContinueMessage(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> activity)
    {
        blablabla
    }
}
```

How can I call the childDialog and go directly into ContinueMessage instead of starting from the first task?

Thank you

Comment: Though their doc doesn't say so, it seems like not possible: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dd/d5e/interface_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_i_dialog.html#a0053d24b10eb4a241e546ce021c7150d

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not a `Call` to a child dialog but a `Forward`, which will automatically start a treatment based on the message that you are providing.